# Log4j ThreadContext.clear() not available with auto-complete?

Tags: java, log4j

according to the [Log4j documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) I can call

`ThreadContext.clear();`

but in my IDE I do not get `clear()` as an available method and I also get compilation errors, I only see clearAll(), etc., why? What is missing on the classpath?

Log4j Version 2.16.0 is used.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1594389, the `clear()` method is replaced with `clearMap()` (it was already deprecated when it was removed).

Comment: I'm using `clearAll()` now.